# PowerShell - CSV - Multiple Headers and Values - Foreach - Use Header and Value

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV -

```
title,client,tech,name,version,createdby,created
sampleTitle,MyCompany,Office365,sampleMonday,11.0,Luke Wilkins,2020-05-08T19:10:08Z
```

I'd like to enumerate through that CSV and use both the header and the value. Is there a way without specifying $variable.title, $variable.client etc

cheers

Comment: Does that mean that your CSV file contains only one (value) row?

Comment: Please elaborate on: "*Is there a way without specifying `$variable.title`, `$variable.client` etc.*", how do you want to reference the values instead? By column index?. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options depending on how you want to use them. I'm going to expand your example to help all of us.

Create the sample file

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
title,client,tech,name,version,createdby,created
sampleTitle1,MyCompany1,Office365,sampleMonday,11.0,Luke Wilkins,2020-05-08T19:10:08Z
sampleTitle2,MyCompany2,Office365,sampleMonday,12.0,Luke Wilkins,2020-05-08T19:10:08Z
'@ | Out-File $tempfile -Encoding utf8
```

Import the CSV

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv $tempfile
```

To simply get each header/value this is one way.

```
$csvdata | foreach {
    $_.psobject.properties | foreach {
        "Name: {0}`nValue: {1}" -f $_.name,$_.value
    }
}
```

Which shows (trimmed)

```
Name: title
Value: sampleTitle1
Name: client
Value: MyCompany1
Name: tech
Value: Office365
Name: name
Value: sampleMonday
Name: version
Value: 11.0
Name: createdby
Value: Luke Wilkins
Name: created
Value: 2020-05-08T19:10:08Z
```

Something I frequently do is create custom objects with the headers as the properties.

```
$csvdata | foreach {
    $ht = [ordered]@{}
    $_.psobject.properties | foreach {$ht += @{$_.name = $_.value}}
    [pscustomobject]$ht
} -OutVariable hashtable
```

Which shows and stores the following output

```
title     : sampleTitle1
client    : MyCompany1
tech      : Office365
name      : sampleMonday
version   : 11.0
createdby : Luke Wilkins
created   : 2020-05-08T19:10:08Z

title     : sampleTitle2
client    : MyCompany2
tech      : Office365
name      : sampleMonday
version   : 12.0
createdby : Luke Wilkins
created   : 2020-05-08T19:10:08Z
```

And if you need to create a property list out of the column headers you can use

```
$props = $csvdata | select -First 1 | foreach {$_.psobject.properties.name}
```

or

```
$props = (Get-Content $tempfile -TotalCount 1).split(',')
```

And we can use the properties to access the data in the hashtable variable like this.

```
$props |  foreach {$hashtable.$_}
```

Or by using the property index

```
1..3 | foreach {$hashtable.($props[$_])}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do something like what you ask for.  You can iterate through the records of the CSV and within that,  iterate through the fields of each record,  and set up local variables that equate the field name to the value of the field in the record.

I used this technique in a little tool I wrote up a few years back:

```
 <#
.NOTES
    Script: Expand-Csv    Rev:  3.2
    By:     DGC           Date: 2-21-19
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates multiple expansions of a template,
    driven by data in a CSV file.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function is a table driven template tool. 

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.
#>
function Expand-csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $driver,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $template
    )
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of sample uses of this tool.  One uses a template to generate SQL statements and the other uses a template to generate invocations of java from powershell.

```
    Example 1:  Driver
    ------------------
    
privs,table,user
ALL,Employees,DBA
READ,Employees,Analyst
"READ, WRITE", Employees, Application
ALL,Departments,DBA
READ,Departments,"Analyst, Application"
    

privs       table       user                
-----       -----       ----                
ALL         Employees   DBA                 
READ        Employees   Analyst             
READ, WRITE Employees   Application         
ALL         Departments DBA                 
READ        Departments Analyst, Application


   
    Example 1:  Template
    --------------------
    

grant $privs 
   on $table 
   to $user;

    
    Example 1:  Results
    -------------------

grant ALL 
   on Employees 
   to DBA;


grant READ 
   on Employees 
   to Analyst;


grant READ, WRITE 
   on Employees 
   to Application;


grant ALL 
   on Departments 
   to DBA;


grant READ 
   on Departments 
   to Analyst, Application;

   
    Example 2:  Driver
    ------------------
    
NAME,ID
John,18
Dave,19
Carmen,20
Eric,21
Tom,22
Lisa,23
Kyle,24
    

NAME   ID
----   --
John   18
Dave   19
Carmen 20
Eric   21
Tom    22
Lisa   23
Kyle   24


    
    Example 2:  Template
    --------------------
    
& java -jar --create -user $name -id $id -file D:/HR/$name-$id-form.pdf
   
    Example 2:  Results
    -------------------
& java -jar --create -user John -id 18 -file D:/HR/John-18-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Dave -id 19 -file D:/HR/Dave-19-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Carmen -id 20 -file D:/HR/Carmen-20-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Eric -id 21 -file D:/HR/Eric-21-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Tom -id 22 -file D:/HR/Tom-22-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Lisa -id 23 -file D:/HR/Lisa-23-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Kyle -id 24 -file D:/HR/Kyle-24-form.pdf
```

Note that, in the template,  I didn't have to put $variable.user  etc.